# How much power should I supply to L293d shield to run 4 tt gear dc motors and 1 servo sg90?

Tags: arduino-uno, l293d

I'm new to Arduino. I am trying to making an obstacle avoiding car using Arduino Uno and L293d motor driver shield.

Four tt gear dc motors and 1 servo motor were connected. How much power should I supply or which batteries and how much should I use? Also, how do I increase the speed of the motor? It's max is 255 in shield but that it is slow.

Comment: The motors require the voltage that they require, whatever that is. You have to provide enough current to cover the peak consumption of your whole setup, plus ideally a bit more for "headroom".

Comment: What is tt? What's a "tt gear dc motor"?

Comment: The 255 only mean 100% duty cycle, so fully on motor. When that is too slow, you need to check, if younare operating the motor at its specified voltage and current. You can only get the max speed and force from a motor, when you are powering it woth the right voltage and provide enough current for it. We cannot know, what motor you exactly have. Look for the maximum current (stall current, as the motor draw max, when it cannot move) and the correct operaring voltage in the datasheet or product site of your motor. You should be able to get it from your vendor, where you bought the motor

Comment: Also check, if the motor driver can handle the voltage and current, that you need for the motor

Comment: Tt gear motor means BO gear motor yellow coloured

Comment: I had supplied power from my laptop so it is enough for motors

Comment: Also my motors are not working at initialI have to give some force then it works automatically

Comment: So may be problem is in shield